# Leaflet polyline SmoothFactor range

Tags: javascript, leaflet, simplify

According to LeafLet documentation PolyLine has a "smoothFactor"  parameter :
http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polyline
which allows polyline simplification to improve performance. Does anyone know what is the range (e.g. min and max values) and if you noticed a performance improvement using it? I tried different values like 0.1, 1, 5, 10, 100, and did not notice a change in zoom/panning performance at all.

Comment: did you ever find the answer?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a demo: "[example of leaflets built-in Simplification - Polyline_smoothFactor](http://bl.ocks.org/milkbread/5933662)"

Answer (score 3):

The default value is 1. Larger numbers will improve performance and smooth polygon shapes. In my experience I ran about 10,000 shapes using `smoothFactor=3`. The performance improvement was barely noticeable (1/4 of a second faster loading time) but the shapes (polygons) were way too simplistic, turning almost every shape into triangles and squares.